# Entity Framework child with multiple Parent Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have 3 classes inheriting from **OwnableSpaceObject** that has 2 navigation properties to their children via ICollections.

From the **OwnableSpaceObject** I want to be able to have a class like *AddChild* which will add one of the child classes to the ICollection and save it to the database.

Here is the **OwnableSpaceObject** base class:

```
public abstract class OwnableSpaceObject : SpaceObject
{
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public int? ResourcesId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ResourcesId")]
    public virtual Resources Resources { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Structure> Structures { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ship> Ships { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the method I'm trying to use:

```
public Structure CheckOrAddChild(StructureType _structureType)
{
    using (ChronosContext db = new ChronosContext())
    {
        var structure = Structures != null ? Structures.FirstOrDefault(x =>   x.StructureTypeId == _structureType.Id) : null;
        if (structure == null)
        {
             Structure newStructure = new Structure(_structureType.Id);
             Structures.Add(newStructure); //this should add the Ship to the database and link it to the parent OwnableSpaceObject right? It errors out right here saying that Structures is null
             db.SaveChanges();

             structure = newStructure;
         }
         return structure;
    }
 }
```

And similarly an overloaded CheckOrAddChild for adding Ships:

```
public virtual Ship CheckOrAddChild(ShipType _shipType)
        {
            using (ChronosContext db = new ChronosContext())
            {
                var ship = Ships != null ? Ships.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ShipTypeId == _shipType.Id) : null;
                if (ship == null)
                {
                    Ship newShip = new Ship(_shipType.Id);
                    Ships.Add(newShip); //this should add the Ship to the database and link it to the parent OwnableSpaceObject right? It errors out right here saying that Ships is null
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    ship = newShip;
                }
                return ship;
            }
        }
```

Here is basically what the Ships and Structures class looks like:

```
public class Ship
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CurrentAmount { get; set; }
        public int BuildingAmount { get; set; }

        public int ShipTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ShipTypeId")]
        public virtual ShipType ShipType { get; set; }
}
```

The Ship/Structure class does not have a navigation property to OwnableSpaceObject because it then crate one huge table for all of my Fleets/Asteroids/Planets because they all inherit from OwnableSpaceObject. I want to keep Fleets/Asteroids/Planets separate in the tables but be able to still attach Ships and Structures to them. Currently EF is making 3 columns in the Ships/Structures tables named "Asteroid_Id", "Planet_Id", and "Fleet_Id" respectively. Should I just make a navigation property for each of these and manually link them up myself? I was trying to avoid this in order to avoid repetitive code.

Anyone have any ideas for this? I've been researching for the past 2 days and I'm about to have a nervous breakdown!